# upgrade or downgrade a running AWS EC2 instance without changing its public ip?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is it possible to upgrade or downgrade a running EC2 instance without affecting its public IP or without shutting it down? Also, there is no elastic IP attach to it.

Comment: why isn't there an elastic IP?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to upgrade or downgrade the software, then yes you can. Just be careful. Most of the time you can upgrade parts or all of software like Apache and only have it take effect when you restart it.

If you mean hardware, attached volumes, instance size etc, then no you will have to stop it before you can modify it.

Of course, you can take an AMI of the machine and spin up a replica, switch over to it or upgrade, or vice versa, then move your public IP over to the new machine. As long as you keep the file system in sync during the switch over, it should be seamless.

Comment: I mean to say upgrade/downgrade of hardware. As i said there is no elastic ip attach to it. So, i think we cannot attach the same public ip to the machine after launching it from replica, right? or can we?

Comment: @scrowler, if the public IP is not an Elastic IP, moving it from one instance to another is impossible.  These addresses come from a pool and are not under user control.

Comment: Sorry - you may have to put up with some downtime while you reboot and upgrade then. Call it scheduled maintenance